# filter a dataset under specific conditions in R

Tags: r, filter, conditional-statements

i have a dataframe structured like this:

```
 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 

 A. B. C.    D.    E. 
 C  C. D.    K.             
 A. B. C. D. E. F. G.
```

where there are empty cells.

i want to filter the data frame according this condition:

For every rows of the dataframe, if there are at least **two values** different from blank values in the columns  **V4, V5, V6, V7** take the row. Otherwise, delete it.

```
 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 

 A. B. C.    D.    E.     
 A. B. C. D. E. F. G.
```

How could I do?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I am not understanding, what exactly your condition is.

Comment: What about `df[apply(df[,c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")], 1, function(row) length(unique(row[nchar(row) > 0])) > 2),]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rowSums`

```
df[rowSums((df!='')[,c('V4','V5','V6','V7')])>=2,]
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
1 A. B. C.    D.    E.
3 A. B. C. D. E. F. G.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subset the data frame, first setting an index that sums a logical operator for each column, as in the example below:

```
df <- data.frame(V4 = c('A', '', 'C'),
                 V5 = c('A', '', 'C'),
                 V6 = c('A', 'B', ''))

  V4 V5 V6
1  A  A  A
2        B
3  C  C   

df <- df[(df$V4 != '') + (df$V5 != '') + (df$V6 != '') >= 2, ]
```

Output

```
  V4 V5 V6
1  A  A  A
3  C  C
```

When you sum the logical operators (testing whether the variable is empty '') they generate a numeric value representing the number of true values found. In your example you want to set the condition of having at least 2 columns satisfy the `!= ''` condition.